# Elliptic grid mapping

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider PDE ∂^2u/∂x^2+∂^2u/∂y^2+ 4 = 0.
[On the physical grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zOsz.png) with some boundary conditions.
I already solve this PDE on the original grid.

Then map the problem into a uniform square (ξ,η) based on the elliptic maps
∂^2ξ/∂x^2+∂^2ξ/∂y^2=0
∂^2η/∂x^2+∂^2η/∂y^2=0
I try to use the [formula here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PbrW.png) to find the corresponding (x,y) coordinate at the new grid (ξ,η) but the equations seem not can be solved by hand. I wonder how can I calculate the solution u on the grid space(ξ,η).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).